# использовать translate.google.ru из своего Node.JS приложения

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

Начитавшись на Хабре цикл статей **"Web scraping при помощи Node.js"**
сделал скрейпинг сайта `ferra.ru`, и захотел для эксперимента сделать приложение переводчик. Идея такая, ввожу слово на ENG, приложение на node.js пересылает его на **translate.google.ru**, вывожу в консоли результат - слово на русском языке. [Строка запроса (перевожу на русский слово Speed)](https://translate.google.ru/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=Speed).

Сначала проверил в браузере, делаю <kbd>F12</kbd> на странице, ага, есть `<span class="tlid-translation ..">` в него вложен `<span class="title ..">` в котором собственно перевод. По началу воодушевился, мол сейчас на cheerio распарсю полученную страницу и готов переводчик ;-) наивный ;-)

По факту мой запрос возвращает только пустую стартовую страницу переводчика **translate.google.ru** даже без полей ввода информации.

Так же в браузере посмотрел что происходит при вводе [ссылки](https://translate.google.ru/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=Speed)

1. собственно загружаются translate.google.ru (и он возвращает cookie)
2. далее многочисленные скрипты и ресурсы
3. где-то на середине загрузки, пролетает GET запрос с моим словом "speed": https://translate.google.ru/translate_a/single?client=webapp&sl=en&tl=ru&hl=ru&dt=at&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&source=bh&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=1&tk=747203.915042&q=speed
4. В ответ который возвращается массив в котором содержится и начальное слово и его перевод:
   [[["скорость", "Speed", null, null, 0] - поймав этот ответ можно было бы остановится

Я конечно сам буду думать как решить задачу, но хотел бы от сообщества получить наставления в какую сторону думать (в последнюю очередь, использовать Яндекс API для яндекс.переводчика ;-) )

С уважением, Герасим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помаявшись с HTTP запросами, я уткнулся в нерешаемую [тему подсчёта HASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053442/google-translate-tts-api-blocked) . Поэтому пошёл по пути эмуляции браузера, воспользовавшись [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare)
Вот черновой исходник, из командной строки беру одно английское слово для перевода на русский язык, запускается браузер Electron, на полученной странице нахожу элементы содержащие перевод, извлекаю из них перевод, показываю в консоли ответ.

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false })

    let engWord = process.argv[2];//беру слово для перевода
    //формирую строку запроса (если потребуется перевести несколько слов, то в запросе они разделены пробелами)
    var URL=`https://translate.google.ru/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=${engWord}`;
    console.log(URL);//контроль полученного пути
    /*это пример какие элементы я буду искать на странице
    <span class="tlid-translation translation"> 
      <span title="">скорость</span> 
    ответ содержится в span`aх вложенных в span с class="tlid-translation 
    */
            nightmare
              .goto(URL)
              .evaluate(() => {
                  /*выбираю span`ы вложенные в span c классом tlid-translation*/
                  let elements = document.querySelector('.tlid-translation').childNodes
                  let i = elements.length
                  let a = []
                  while (i--) {
                    /*собираю ответы в массив.. в обратном порядке ;-)*/
                    a.push(elements[i].innerHTML)
                  }
                  return a
                })
              .end()
              .then(result=> {
                  console.log(result)//перевод
                })
              .catch(error => {
                console.error('Search failed:', error)
              })
```